# Slow performance using Nlog when compared to log4net

Tags: .net-core, log4net, nlog, dotnet-core-pack

We recently updated the logging framework for our ASP.NET Core Web API project from log4net to NLog and when we do performance testing request/second rate served NLog is way less when compared it to NLog. Below is my NLog configuration file.

Please suggest any ideas on our performance issue using NLog.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true"
      internalLogLevel="info"
      internalLogFile="C:\temp\internal-nlog.txt">

  <!-- enable asp.net core layout renderers -->
  <extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore"/>
    <add assembly="SumoLogic.Logging.NLog"/>
  </extensions>

  <!-- the targets to write to -->
  <targets>
    <!-- write logs to console -->
    <target xsi:type="ColoredConsole" name="allConsole" formatMessage="false" layout="${longdate}|${level:uppercase=true}|${message}" />

    <target name="sumoLogic" type="SumoLogicTarget" formatMessage="false" layout="${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd HH\:mm\:ss.fff} ${level}, ${message}${exception:format=tostring}${newline}">
      <Url>#{Logging__SumoLogic__EndpointUrl}</Url>
      <ConnectionTimeout>30000</ConnectionTimeout>
      <SourceName>#{Logging__SumoLogic__SourceName}</SourceName>
      <SourceCategory>#{Logging__SumoLogic__SourceCategory}</SourceCategory>
      <UseConsoleLog>true</UseConsoleLog>
    </target>

    <target name="bufferedSumoLogic" type="BufferedSumoLogicTarget" formatMessage="false" layout="${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd HH\:mm\:ss.fff} ${level}, ${message}${exception:format=tostring}${newline}">
      <Url>#{Logging__SumoLogic__EndpointUrl}</Url>
      <SourceName>#{Logging__SumoLogic__SourceName}</SourceName>
      <SourceCategory>#{Logging__SumoLogic__SourceCategory}</SourceCategory>
      <ConnectionTimeout>30000</ConnectionTimeout>
      <RetryInterval>5000</RetryInterval>
      <MessagesPerRequest>10</MessagesPerRequest>
      <MaxFlushInterval>10000</MaxFlushInterval>
      <FlushingAccuracy>250</FlushingAccuracy>
      <MaxQueueSizeBytes>500000</MaxQueueSizeBytes>
      <UseConsoleLog>true</UseConsoleLog>
    </target>
  </targets>

  <!-- rules to map from logger name to target -->
  <rules>
    <!-- Skip non-critical Microsoft logs and so log only own logs -->
    <logger name="Microsoft.*" maxLevel="Info" final="true" />

    <!-- Write all debug messages to console -->
    <logger name="*" minlevel="#{Logging__ConsoleLog__LevelMin}" writeTo="allConsole" />

    <!-- Write to sumo buffered log -->
    <logger name="*" minlevel="#{Logging__BufferedLog__LevelMin}" maxlevel="#{Logging__BufferedLog__LevelMax}" writeTo="bufferedSumoLogic" />

    <!-- Write to sumo instant log -->
    <logger name="*" minlevel="#{Logging__InstantLog__LevelMin}" maxlevel="#{Logging__InstantLog__LevelMax}" writeTo="sumoLogic" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Comment: I think it depends on the sumo targets. You could try disabling logging to the console, as consoles are slow to write.

Comment: Could you also paste the log4net-config that you are using in comparison? What does `formatMessage="false"` mean? Have you checked the NLog `internalLogFile` for errors / warnings ? Does performance improve when you configure `<UseConsoleLog>false</UseConsoleLog>` ?

Comment: @manideep tried disabling the Console target?

Comment: @Julian Yes I tried disabling the console target too. but no luck.

Answer (score 5):

Unluckily you can't speed up what the targets do inside, they could be doing web requests, db calls, writing to files, etc. (and I guess that's OK after all) BUT you can avoid blocking the application thread from which you are logging, that's for me the important matter here.

Just add `async="true"` to your `targets` element, it should read:
`<targets async="true">`

A little explanation from the link below:

> Asynchronous target wrapper allows the logger code to execute more
>   quickly, by queuing messages and processing them in a separate thread.
>   You should wrap targets that spend a non-trivial amount of time in
>   their Write() method with asynchronous target to speed up logging.

Also have in mind that some targets don't work well in async mode (you'll discover by testing, in my case `RollbarSharp`), so you can create another `targets` section for those ones.

You can get more info here: https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/AsyncWrapper-target

Good luck!